# HttpClient problem with URLs which include curly braces

Tags: android, httpclient

I am using HttpClient for my android application. At some point, I have to fetch data from remote locations. Below is the snippet how I made use of HttpClient to get the response.

```
String url_s = "https://mydomain.com/abc/{5D/{B0blhahblah-blah}I1.jpg"; //my url string
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url_s));
```

It works absolutely fine in most cases but not when there is some curly braces in my url which is String basically. The stack trace shows me the index of curly braces saying Invalid character. 
So I tried to create URI from encoded URL.

```
URL url = new URL(url_s);
URI uri = url.toURI();
response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
```

After doing so, i didn't get the result from remote location at all. I worked around the problem and fixed it by replacing the curly brace

- "{" with "%7B"
- "}" with "%7D"

But I am not totally satisfy with my solution. Are there any better solutions? Anything neat and not hard-coded like mine?

Comment: what does `URI.encode(url)` return?

Comment: Sorry. I will edit the question. It isn't URI encode method. I created URL to encode the string and change to URI using toURI() method.

Comment: Have you tried URLEncoder.encode(url_s)?

Comment: Yes, I did. Didn't work either. The stack trace shows "host may not be null".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The strict answer is that you should never have curly braces in your URL

A full description of valid URL's can be found in [RFC1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html)

The pertinent part for this answer is as follows

> Unsafe:
>
> Characters can be unsafe for a number of reasons.  The space
>   character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear and
>   insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed or
>   typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs.
>   The characters "<" and ">" are unsafe because they are used as the
>   delimiters around URLs in free text; the quote mark (""") is used to
>   delimit URLs in some systems.  The character "#" is unsafe and should 
>   always be encoded because it is used in World Wide Web and in other
>   systems to delimit a URL from a fragment/anchor identifier that might 
>   follow it.  The character "%" is unsafe because it is used for
>   encodings of other characters.  Other characters are unsafe because
>   gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify
>   such characters. These characters are "{", "}", "|", "\", "^", "~",
>   "[", "]", and "`".
>
> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL. For
>   example, the character "#" must be encoded within URLs even in
>   systems that do not normally deal with fragment or anchor
>   identifiers, so that if the URL is copied into another system that
>   does use them, it will not be necessary to change the URL encoding.

In order to bypass the problem you have been experiencing you must encode your url.

The problem you experienced with the "host may not be null" error will happen when the entire url is being encoded including the https://mydomain.com/ part so it gets confused.  You only want to encode the last part of the URL called the path.

The solution is to use the Uri.Builder class to build your URI from the individual parts which should encode the path in the process

You will find a detailed description in the [Android SDK Uri.Builder reference documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html)

Some trivial examples using your values are:

```
Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse("https://mydomain.com").buildUpon();
b.path("/abc/{5D/{B0blhahblah-blah}I1.jpg");
Uri u = b.build();
```

Or you can use chaining:

```
    Uri u = Uri.parse("https://mydomain.com").buildUpon().path("/abc/{5D/{B0blhahblah-blah}I1.jpg").build();
```

Comment: That's OK ... that's why I provided a solution to the problem that you were having by using the Uri.Builder.  I have tested the code and it should work as you expect. Please indicate if there is more information you require before accepting the answer.

Comment: how do i convert andorid.net.Uri to java.net.URI? HttpClient doesn't seem to work with Uri. It accepts either string or URI.

Sorry that my above comment get deleted. I am a starter at this site and not familiar with functionality.

Comment: Just use toString(). e.g. u.toString(). If you are happy with answer then please "accept as answer"

Answer (score 3):

Except RFC1738 has been obsolete for over a decade, has been superseded by rfc3986 and there is no indication in:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

That curly braces are unsafe (In fact, the RFC does not contain a single curly brace character anywhere). Furthermore, I've tried URI's in browsers that contain curly braces, and they work fine.

Also note the OP is using a class called URI - which should definitely be following 3986, at the very least, if not 3987.

However, oddly, IRIs defined in:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987

Have the note that:

> Systems accepting IRIs MAY also deal with the printable characters
> in    US-ASCII that are not allowed in URIs, namely "<", ">", '"',
> space,    "{", "}", "|", "", "^", and "`", in step 2 above.  If these
> characters are found but are not converted, then the conversion
> SHOULD fail.  Please note that the number sign ("#"), the percent
> sign ("%"), and the square bracket characters ("[", "]") are not part
> of the above list and MUST NOT be converted.

In other words, it looks like the RFCs themselves have some issues.