# Can I use Uri.Builder from Android SDK in Google App Engine (Java Project)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, uri

I noticed the [Uri.Builder in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742274/617373) And I wondered if I can use it in my GAE project in eclipse

I want to do something like

```
Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse("https://mydomain.com").buildUpon();
b.path("/abc/{5D/{B0blhahblah-blah}I1.jpg");
Uri u = b.build();
```

I cant find a way to add the Android SDK to my Google New Web Application Project

Is it possible and how?

Thanks in advance...I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uri.Builder` creates Android `Uri` objects, not Java `URI` objects. You would need to:

1. Grab [the source code to `Uri`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/Uri.java) from the open source repository.
2. Refactor it into your own package, probably.
3. Remove everything that refers to other Android classes.
4. Make any other modifications you feel you need to consume the resulting `Uri` objects.

Comment: The "Refactor it into your own package, probably." part is gonna be very unpleasant :/ seems like several/dozens of files will be needed to be included in my project.. :( cause they are a must in the Uri class...

Comment: I'm not going to do it , At the time of asking I wasn't aware of the JAVA URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF8"); existence...