# android: google APi OAuth 2.0 - error 400 getting user info

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, gdata-api

I have the following on a web servlet:

EDITED:

```
public String tryGoogleAuthentication(String auth_token){

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {

        //connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2v1/tokeninfo?access_token={"+auth_token+"}")).openConnection();
       connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/user info")).openConnection();
       connection.setRequestMethod("GET");          
       connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer {"+auth_token+"}");
       connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "googleapis.com");

        //read response
        String response = fromInputStreamToString(connection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(response);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return CONST.STATUS_OK;
}
```

In android:

```
    private void googleAuthenticate(){
    try {
        mOAauthHelper = new OAuthHelper("something.net", "xxxxxxxxxx", 
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "alex://myScheme");
        String uri = mOAauthHelper.getRequestToken();

        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(uri)));

                    //Intent i = new Intent(this, GoogleOAUTHActivity.class);
                    //i.putExtra(GoogleOAUTHActivity.GOOGLE_OAUTH_ENDPOINT_KEY, uri);           
                     //startActivity(i);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    //super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    String oauthToken = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
    String oauthVerifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

    if(oauthToken != null){
        authorizeGoogleSessionToServer(oauthToken);
    }
}
```

After this, I send the request token to my servlet where I tried to get user profile, but with no success.

Could you please tell me what's wrong and why I'm getting error 400 from google?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can see a few issues with this already

1. you [should never have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742274/431841) `curly braces` in your URL or even in the [Bearer header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-21#section-2.1) as stated in the draft.

> connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=**{**"+auth_token+"**}**")).openConnection()

2. `400` means that you're missing something in your request, there is probably more information about it in the same response as specific error node.
3. Finally, take care, `oauth_verifier` param is from OAuth 1.

I suggest you test your request URL's, using the [Google OAuth2 playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground)

Good luck!

Comment: 3. I do not use oauthVerifier.

Comment: 1.Please see: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall. I changed the request(remove curly braces and added headers instead). Please see above for the edit.

Comment: Also, using Google OAuth2 playground and hitting find availables URIs, I get :"Something bad happened: invalid_token"

Comment: Could you please send me a request example if possible? The curly braces were presented in google docs : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall

Comment: Also I tried get www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=youraccess_token, but 401 error was returned.

Comment: Hi, the problem are the curly braces again. In the documentation is used only as a formal representation of a variable.

Comment: i.e.: curl -i "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo" -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.BTWG5USBcO9EvJcXGhYI5PKYzuL-GvrMA0ZIba-ynKtNLg"
Just replace the token string with your own.

Comment: Now I get error 401. Also, when sending without headers: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=4/otJJ2lp7yyu2VfYNVTAO79QwJ012

Comment: after reading your url, and according to the format of that token, it is not an access_token is more like an autorization_code (Step 1). What you need to do is to exchange the authorization_code for an access_token (Step 2).

Comment: It appears that I need to exchange this auth code. I tried with no success. I opened another question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208324/android-google-acc-exchange-the-authorization-code-for-an-access-token. Please help me if possible. I think your answer is the good one(If I will get access token, than everything will be ok), so I will give you the 50 bounty points. But please help me in the other question too. Thank you.