# android google acc: Exchange the authorization_code for an access_token

Tags: android, oauth

I tried to to exchange auth code for an access token, but no success. I need to access user profile.
Here is my code:

first get auth code:

EDITED:

```
private void googleAuthenticate(){
    try {
        mOAauthHelper = new OAuthHelper("something.net", "xxxxx", 
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "alex://myScheme");
        String uri = mOAauthHelper.getRequestToken();

        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(uri)));

       //Intent i = new Intent(this, GoogleOAUTHActivity.class);
       //i.putExtra(GoogleOAUTHActivity.GOOGLE_OAUTH_ENDPOINT_KEY, uri);            
       //startActivity(i);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failedAuthenticatingAtGoogle();
    }
}
```

and

```
public OAuthHelper(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String scope,
        String callbackUrl) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    mConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    mProvider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
            "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(scope, "utf-8"),
            "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken",
            "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?hd=default");
    mProvider.setOAuth10a(true);
    mCallbackUrl = (callbackUrl == null ? OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND : callbackUrl);
}
```

and

```
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    System.out.println("onNewIntent");

    try {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String oauthToken = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
       // String oauthToken = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        System.out.println(oauthToken);

        if(oauthToken != null){
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", oauthToken));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "something.net"));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "xxxxxx"));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "alex://myScheme"));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code")); //Leave this line how it is   
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            System.out.println(responseBody); // That just logs it into logCat

            //authorizeGoogleSessionToServer(oauthToken);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and I get:
   {
       "error" : "invalid_request"
   }

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *double encoding* the `redirect_uri` param.

It should look something like::

```
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "your_own_redirect_URI"));
```

Also, you should be careful to not mix both implementations of the protocol (OAuth1 and OAuth2). They look the same but are not equal.

Comment: I've removed URLEncoder from redirect_uri and from client_secret, but still invalid_request comes from the server. I've edited my post with the new changes. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I suppose that OAuth Consumer Key is the client id and OAuth Consumer Secret is the client secret.

Comment: I realize that your Redirect URI is invalid (because of the standard), you should use one of you have been authorized in your Google APIs Console > API Access > Client ID for web applications > Redirect URIs

Comment: the terms OAuth Consumer Key and OAuth Consumer Secret are from OAuth1, take care with do not mix both. I recommend to not use an implementation of that version (already deprecated).